# How to update one table based on the count value of another table while matching ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, sql-update

There are two tables: *articles* and *comments*. There is an association between them: each *comment* holds the *article id* it belongs to.

```
-----------------------------
 articles
----+-------+----------------
 id | title | comments_count
----+-------+----------------
 1  |  aaa  |              0
 2  |  bbb  |              0
 3  |  ccc  |              0
 4  |  ddd  |              0
 5  |  eee  |              0
 6  |  fff  |              0
```

...

```
-------------------------------
 comments
----+-------------+------------
 id |        text | article_id
----+-------------+------------
 1  | aaa comment |          1
 2  | aaa comment |          1
 3  | fff comment |          6
 4  | bbb comment |          2
 5  | ddd comment |          4
 6  | bbb comment |          2
```

The *articles* table further has a columns which holds the current count of associated *comments*.
Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab15e/2) with a basic setup of the described tables.

After having imported a bunch of *articles* and *comments* how can I update the *comments_count* on every *article* to reflect number of associated *comments*?

Comment: +1 for a well formed question, including a fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE articles a
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
  article_id,
  count(*) as count
 FROM comments
 GROUP BY article_id
) AS b
ON a.id = b.article_id
SET comments_count = COALESCE(b.count, 0);
```

I used it on your sqlfiddle (had to put it in the schema section) then selecting all the articles showed the correct counts for me.

Updated so it will always set the correct value (you can run multiple times and after deletes, etc)

Comment: A left join would be better if an article has no comments.

Comment: Possibly. I think it depends on if articles has a count populated and if it is default 0 or null and if comments can be deleted.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Looks good so far. `comment_count` has a default of `0`. If *comments* are deleted I would like to be able to re-run the command to update *comments_count*.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I just tested the updated statement on a dataset of 120,000 items. Compared to the former `JOIN` version without `COALESCE` the `LEFT JOIN` version takes **~ 4.4 times longer**. Can you describe why?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, the most *classical* version:

```
UPDATE articles a
SET comments_count= (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM comments c
    WHERE a.id=c.article_id
);
```

Some benchmarkings to compare efficiency? Just for the record, I'm sure Daniel's answer is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for completeness. The `JOIN` should outreach the cascade.

Comment: heya thanx it works, is there any other way to achieve same result

Comment: @pitu sure, see the other answer. Mine is the classical (no join), whilst Daniel's is more efficient.